# Azure Purview Scan Fails on Azure File

Tags: azure, azure-files, azure-purview

I am trying to run a Purview Scan from self managed runtime to Azure File and it is consistently failing. Unfortunately, there is not much help (logs) from the platform (Purview) other than a correlation id!

Both the Blob and File share in the same storage account. I can get to scan the blob successfully using Service Principal.

[image: Purview Azure File Scans Fail]

As of now, you can't use anything but storage account key as credential to scan Azure File! I did configure the credential in Key Vault and granted Purview MSI (and Service Principal) access to read the secrets. However, I haven't have a success to scan Azure File. Any reason why Purview scanner is failing? Also, any clue where to look for debugging logs in Purview platform?

[image: Scan details with very little info on error!]

AWS S3 data source scan is consistently failing. I have the latest version of Self Hosted Runtime. Tried to use Azure Managed Runtime but none is working.

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. Were you able to resolve yours. If so, could you please share your solution/suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: @nam- No, it never got it to work for Azure File when Purview instance is private. It worked for me when I tested Azure Public instance. However, we can't use public endpoint for corporate world. I gave up but documented my unsuccessful effort at https://blogs.aspnet4you.com/2022/05/02/azure-purview-private-network-architecture-and-lesson-learned/

Answer (score 0):

I just performed using manage identity, It’s working fine for me. you can follow below steps:

**First,** go to ***Azure purview studio*** -> Data map -> ***Register blob storage*** -> then go to blob storage as shown in the below image ***assign roles to blob storage.*** Now in Azure Purview perform a scan.

[image: Ref1]
[image: Ref2]
[image: Ref3]
[image: Ref4]
[image: Ref5]
[image: Ref6]

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/quickstart-create-collection

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/troubleshoot-connections

Comment: @BhanunagasaiVamsi-MT- Thank you so much for responding to my question. The issue is not with Azure Blob! It is to do with Azure File. Would you be able to confirm if Azure File scan is working? I can't scan AWS S3 either. Lesson learn is being documented at https://blogs.aspnet4you.com/2022/05/02/azure-purview-private-network-architecture-and-lesson-learned/